# TS2339: Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type 'Model<Document, {}>'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have defined a schema method by using this code. While I use in the service. It is showing a error.

// model

```js
export interface User extends mongoose.Document {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please tell us your name.']
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select a username.']
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide us your email.'],
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide us your email.']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select a password.'],
        minLength: 8
        select: false
    },
    passwordConfirmation: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please re-enter your password.'],
        minLength: 8,
    },
    comparePassword(password: string): boolean
}
```

// method declared

```js
userSchema.method('comparePassword', function (password: string): boolean {
    if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

// service file

```js
public loginUser  = async(req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
        const {username, password} = req.body;
        if(!username || !password){
            res.status(400).json({
                status: 'failed',
                message: 'Please provide username and password.'
            });
            return next(new AppError('Please provide username and password.', 400));
        } else {
            const person = await [![User][1]][1].comparePassword(password);
            const token = signToken(person._id);
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'success',
                accessToken : token
            });
        }
    }
```

this line shows me the error.

`const person = await User.comparePassword(password);`

This is the screenshot in editor.

[image]

THis is the terminal screenshot

[image]

Can I know what is the problem here. I tried seeing the solution but could not find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was error in exporting the model.

```
export const User = mongoose.model<user>("User", userSchema);
```

And in the exporting interface add declare the function.

```js
export interface user extends mongoose.Document {
    name: String,
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    passwordConfirmation: String,
    comparePassword(candidatePassword: string): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

And the function is defined like this.

```js
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword: string): Promise<boolean> {
    let password = this.password;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, password, (err, success) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(success);
        });
    });
};
```

Then there was error in calling the function `person.comparePassword()`. It should be called after finding the existing user. As @Mohammed Amir Ansari stated. the error was corrected and the actual error was exporting a model.

Answer (score 1):

The Schema method you define will be available with mongoose instances i.e documents in your collection and not with the model. Also you are directly trying to compare the password which should not be the case. You should first check if the user exists or not and if the user found, you can call your **comparePassword()** using the user document, the code for the same will be:

```
public loginUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
    const {
        username,
        password
    } = req.body;
    if (!username || !password) {
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: 'Please provide username and password.'
        });
        return next(new AppError('Please provide username and password.', 400));
    } else {
        const person = await User.findOne({
            username
        });
        if (!person) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'No User Found.'
            });
        }
        const isValidPassword = await person.comparePassword(password);
        if (isValidPassword) {
            const token = signToken(person._id);
            return res.status(200).json({
                status: 'success',
                accessToken: token
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({
                status: 'fail',
                message: 'Invalid Password!!'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, After writing the code for finding the existing user and then calling the function. It still shows the same error. I have added the screenshots of the editor and terminal displaying the errors. Can you please look into that. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for not specifiying the export statement. It worked. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps... Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

for  my case

```
export interface IUserSchema extends Document {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    profilePic?: string;
 
    comparePassword(candidatePassword: string): Promise<boolean>;

}


    
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword =  async  function (candidatePassword: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const user = this as IUserSchema;
    try {
    return  await  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, user.password)

    } catch (error) {
         throw  new Error("some  thing  wrrrong in the "+error)

    }

};
```

how to  used  it

```
 var result = await user.comparePassword(dto.password);
```