# TS[2339]: Property not exist on type '() => Promise<(Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & Omit<IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>) | null>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I've defined the user schema using following:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { Model, Schema } from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

enum LoginType {
  EMAIL = 'email',
  GOOGLE = 'google',
}

interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
  loginTypes: LoginType
  comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function): Promise<Function>
}

interface IUserMethods extends Model<IUser> {
  comparePassword(password: string, callback: Function): Promise<Function>
}

type UserModel = Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods>;

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel, IUserMethods>({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  loginTypes: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    enum: Object.values(LoginType),
  },
})

/* callback = (err: Error, isMatch: any) => {} */
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (
  password: string,
  callback: Function
): Promise<Function> {
  let result
  try {
    result = await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password)
    return callback(null, result)
  } catch (err) {
    return callback(err, result)
  }
}

export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', userSchema)
```

And calling it in the login route, but typescript shows an error `Property 'comparePassword' does not exist on type '() => Promise<(Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & Omit<IUser & { _id: ObjectId; }, never>) | null>'.` on `foundUser.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err: Error, isMatch: any) => {})`

Following is my login route:

```js
router.post('/credentials', (req, res) => {
  /* Check if user exists in database */
  const foundUser = async () => await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })

  if (!foundUser) {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'User does not exist' })
  }

  /* Check if password matches */
  foundUser.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err: Error, isMatch: any) => {})

  const jwt_token = jwt.sign(
    { name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, id: req.body.id },
    JWT_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: '10000' }
  )
  res.status(200).send({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    id: req.body.id,
    jwt_token: jwt_token,
  })
})
```

I've search for it and try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435222/ts2339-property-comparepassword-does-not-exist-on-type-modeldocument) solution before but not working.
While, I found

```js
const a = new User({})
a.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err: Error, isMatch: any) => {})
```

will work fine just like what the mongoose docs said but not working if I use `findOne` before calling `comparePassword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
const foundUser = async () => await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
```

You are defining a **function** called `foundUser` that when called will return the result of `await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })`.

As written, you would need to call the function `foundUser` to actually query MongoDB. Something like:

```
const foundUser = async () => await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
const user = await foundUser();
```

But I think what you intended is something like this:

```
const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
```

Here `foundUser` is not a function, it is the result of the MongoDB query.

Comment: But although I use `const a = async () => await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })` and `const foundUser = a()`, typescript still give me the error. BTW, the type of foundUser is `Promise<(Document<unknown, {}, IUser> & Omit<IUser & { _id: Types.ObjectId; }, never>) | null>`

Comment: I add an `async` before my `(req, res) => {}` to make `const foundUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })` correct and solved it. Thank!